# Creating a Command Button Class - For Word Command Buttons

Tags: vba, button, command, ms-word

I am trying to set some command buttons properties out in bulk . That is trying to set various properties of the command buttons in one go rather than repeat the code for each command button individually.

The document has 30+ command buttons.

In the **Class** - I have put the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cMDButtonGroup As CommandButton

Private Sub cMDButtonGroup_Click()
With cMDButtonGroup

    If   .Caption = "Press" Then

    '  Add some other button properties

    Else

        .Caption = " Complete"


    End If
End With
```

In a **VBA Module** - I have put the code below:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Buttons() As New cMDButtonClass

Sub Buttons()
Dim ButtonCount As Integer
Dim ctl As Control

'   Create the Button objects
ButtonCount = 0
For Each ctl In ActiveDocument.Controls   ' This may be wrong
    If TypeName(ctl) = "CommandButton" Then

            ButtonCount = ButtonCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve Buttons(1 To ButtonCount)
            Set Buttons(ButtonCount).ButtonGroup = ctl
        End If
    End If
Next ctl

End Sub
```

The above may have been sourced from VBA Express? Unfortunately I have lost the link.

Unfortunately I do not know how to proceed to fix this.

**Final Solution**:  Tim's Code works perfectly. You also need to load the buttons

Put the below code in ThisDocument

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

Call SetupButtons


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Deduplicator - This is VBA for word - or am I mistaken?

Comment: These are ActiveX controls from the MSForms type library? In order to address them "generically" you need the InlineShapes collection. Test the "Type" property. If that's correct then you get the control object through InlineShape.OLEObject.Object. I'm currently on a mobile device so can't give you anything more concrete until tomorrow...

Comment: Thank you Very Much Cindy, You are correct they are Active X - Command Buttons - I look forward to your advice  - thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cMDButtonClass (simplified)

```
Public WithEvents oBtn As CommandButton

Private Sub oBtn_Click()
    MsgBox "clicked: " & oBtn.Caption
End Sub
```

In a regular module:

```
Dim colButtons As New Collection '< simpler to manage than an array

Sub SetupButtons()
    Dim ButtonCount As Integer
    Dim ctl, c
    Dim oB As cMDButtonClass

    'Following Cindy's comment...
    For Each ctl In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If Not ctl.OLEFormat Is Nothing Then
            Set c = ctl.OLEFormat.Object
            If TypeName(c) = "CommandButton" Then
                Set oB = New cMDButtonClass
                Set oB.oBtn = c
                colButtons.Add oB
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the code. I have set up the code. When I press the command buttons - no message pops up - I am not sure why?

Comment: Tim thank you for your help this code did the job perfectly. Also thanks Cindy for the initial input :)